# sql - year day to day/month conversion

Tags: conversion, sql, date

suppose I have the following table

```
+-----------+-------------+
|    DAY    |  LEAP YEAR  |
+-----------+-------------+
|    7      |    true     |
|    167    |    false    |
|    43     |    true     |
|    60     |    true     |
|    256    |    false    |
|    340    |    false    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

using only SQL functions, how would one "convert" these year days into actual day/month combinations?
the result would be something like:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|    DAY    |  LEAP YEAR  |   RESULT   |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|    7      |    true     |   7 Jan    |
|    167    |    false    |   16 Jun   |
|    43     |    true     |   12 Feb   |
|    60     |    true     |   29 Feb   |
|    256    |    false    |   13 Sep   |
|    340    |    false    |   6 Dec    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: It would be Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A neat property of leap years is that they are all the same (except for round hundred years). So you could just pick any leap or non-leap year and get the same result for all the others. E.g., 2016 is a leap year, and 2015 is not. Given that information, you can use the `DDD` date formater (day of **year**) and use some `case` expressions to get the information you need:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(day) || 
                 '-' || 
                 CASE leap_year 
                   WHEN 'true' THEN '2016' 
                   ELSE '2015' 
                 END, 
                'DDD-YYYY'), 
         'dd month') AS result
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: thank you @Mureinik, didn't realise explicit years would work just as well, and also that DDD format could be that useful

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way: pick a year that's not a leap year, and one that is a leap year. Put a date = Jan 1 of each year into two variables. Using a CASE statement, add together (day value - 1) and whichever date variable is appropriate. Then use either a case statement or more SQL to get the month name and day from this expression.

```
declare @normal_year_nyd date = '1-1-2015';
declare @leap_year_nyd date = '1-1-2016';
select 
  t.[day], -- highly suggest naming this something other than 'day' to avoid ambiguous code
  t.leap_year, 
  datename(month, dateadd(day, t.[day] - 1, 
    case 
      when t.leap_year = 'false' 
        then @normal_year_nyd
      when t.leap_year = 'true'
        then @leap_year_nyd
      end)
  ) as month_name,
  -- do the same as above replacing "month" with "day" in the dateadd expression
from my_table t
where t.leap_year is not null and t.[day] is not null
```

If you need to handle nulls then you must rewrite the expressions with the case on the outside and add a branch for null.

If you need this to be purely a select statement, just hard code the dates in the case statement rather than using the vars.

Comment: althought a bit more complex solution, this seems to work fine just as well, so thanks @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae